# Why does data-attribute show in link instead of image tag in Rails 4 app?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In a rails 4 app I have the following code in a view:

```
    <% @featured.each do |featured| %>
        <div><%= link_to featured do %>
        <%= image_tag(featured.image.url, data: {slidecaption: featured.title}) %>
        <% end %></div>
        <% end %>
```

I am expecting this to produce the following html:

```
<div>
<a href="pathto/link">
<img alt="imagename" src="pathto/image.jpg" data-slidecaption="Title">
</a>
</div>
```

But I am getting this:

```
<div>
<a href="pathto/link" data-slidecaption="Title">
<img alt="Prelaunchsavethedate" src="pathto/image.jpg">
</a>
</div>
```

I can't seem to figure out why my data-attribute is showing up in the link instead of the image tag. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it still do that if you do `<%= link_to feature_path(featured) do %>` or whatever the path name is?

Comment: If I change the code as suggested I get a no-method error.

undefined method `featured_path'

Comment: I don't know what your routes look like, but there must be a named path you are referring to when you write `<%= link_to featured do %>`, you should be able to see what it is when running `rake routes`. I am suggesting to try linking to that path by name, whatever the name might be.

Comment: Okay so that would be event_path(featured). Still produces the same html as in my original question. I'm sure I'm missing something but it's not obvious to me.